# New @JoinTable causes org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException in nativeQuery and we don't have a clue

Tags: spring, hibernate

This one has our team scratching our heads and we have no idea how to proceed.

**Overview** 
We have two Order types, **CashIn** and **CashOut** with separte entitiy classes and we have one entity of **CustomerDetails**. To avoid unnecessary duplication I set up a *JoinTable* to look up the correct **CustomerDetails** when needed.

There are many more entries in each class but this is what is below relates to this issue.

**class CashIn**

```java
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Order.CustomerDetails", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("customerDetails"))
public class Order extends BaseEntity {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "order_customer_details",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cashin_order_id",  referencedColumnName = "id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "customer_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }
        )
  private CustomerDetails customerDetails;

}
```

**class CashOut**

```java
public class CashOut extends BaseEntity {

  /**
   * The old approach was no good.
   */
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "order_customer_details",
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cashout_order_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "customer_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }
        )
  private CustomerDetails customerDetails;

}
```

**class CustomerDetails**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class CustomerDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id",unique=true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
  private String name;

}
```

**JoinTable**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_customer_details")
public class OrderCustomerDetails extends BaseEntity {

  /**
   * OneToOne OrderCustomerDetails Bridge
   */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "int")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "cashin_order_id", columnDefinition = "bigint")
  private Long cashInOrderId;

  @Column(name = "cashout_order_id", columnDefinition = "bigint")
  private Long cashOutOrderId;

  @Column(name = "customer_details_id", columnDefinition = "bigint")
  private Long customerDetailsId;

  @CreationTimestamp
  @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
  private Date createdDate;
}
```

All of this works as intended, when a **CashIn** or **CashOut** order is checked it looks up the correct entries in the **JoinTable** and fetches the correct **CustomerDetails** entry.

**BUT**

in our scheduled `nativeQuery` call

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
       value = "SELECT o.* FROM orders o JOIN vendors v on o.vendor_id = v.id" +
                " where date_add(o.last_update_date, interval v.order_notification_delay second) < now() AND o.id > 10000")
List<Order> findPaidOrdersRequiringNotification();
```

using a **CashIn** example it returns

```
2019-11-08 12:43:15,404 WARN  [task-scheduler-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2019-11-08 12:43:15,405 ERROR [task-scheduler-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Column 'customer_details_id' not found.
2019-11-08 12:43:21,310 ERROR [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT o.* FROM orders o JOIN vendors v on o.vendor_id = v.id where date_add(o.last_update_date, interval v.order_notification_delay second) < now() AND o.id > 10000]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.findPaidOrdersRequiringNotification(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:97)
    at m6.controller.merchant.SortManipulatingAspect.enableIgnoreCaseSorting(SortManipulatingAspect.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.findPaidOrdersRequiringNotification(Unknown Source)
    at m6.task.orderpaid.OrderPaidService.processPaidOrders(OrderPaidService.java:52)
    at m6.task.orderpaid.OrderPaidService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$307fb413.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at m6.task.orderpaid.OrderPaidService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3843faf7.processPaidOrders(<generated>)
    at m6.task.orderpaid.OrderPaidTask.perform(OrderPaidTask.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2620)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'customer_details_id' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2736)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    ... 80 more
```

After days of testing all I can ascertain is that if the query finds an order it will puke. If there are no hits it'll happily continue without an error.

This only thing that might be different in our case is I have nulls in the **JoinTable**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `order_customer_details` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cashin_order_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cashout_order_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_details_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16583 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='One to One table to link orders to customer details';
```

The `nativeQuery` works perfectly well in MySQL Workbench.

I am at a loss on how to continue. Does any one have anything to suggest for me to check?

Comment: Question. Why do you have OrderCustomerDetails  when you dont' use it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get your question. OrderCustomerDetails is used by the system, it's just not used in the nativeQuery. Using the query in any SQL client is fine but as David Florez suggested below there is more at play

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the query itself but with the results that you are getting from it. You are running a native query that is only retrieving the columns of your `order` table 
`"SELECT o.* FROM orders o ...` but mapping those results to a much more complex class, your `Order` entity that includes complex joins on it, since the query is native, hibernate will not perform all the joins and magic that it usually does behind the scenes. Thast why the query works on MySQL Workbench but not on your app.

This means that if you want your native query to work as you are expecting you will have to do all this joins by hand on your query and then indicate to hibernate how it should map those results o your class using a SqlResultSetMapping or something like that.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David, I thought the very same two days ago and attempted to build the native query to replicate the hibernate magic but got no where. With your nudge I'll investigate further. I was also unaware of SqlResultSetMapping so I have some reading to do.